# How to add a backdrop to tabletop miniature games in a cost effective way?

Tags: backdrops

I play Warhammer with my friends and we frequently take photos of our games. We've spent a lot of time and effort to paint miniatures and scenery, however the photos are often rudely backdropped by someone's kitchen.

[image: photo of warhammer game with window in the background]

The photos done by the Games Workshop studio such as the one below often have backdrops so the battles appear to go on forever.

[image: professional photo of games workshop]

What is the most cost effective way of recreating this effect at home - ideally using iPhone or iPad photo editing software?

Comment: Have you tried changing the angle and position of the camera?

Comment: @xiota yes to a degree and for posed shots you can put a big building behind them. But when you're photographing the "action" so to speak there may not be a convenient bit of scenery behind them

Comment: Not a proper answer because it is not _adding_ a backdrop, but the most cost-effective way of _removing_ the kitchen, furniture etc. is just getting a bed sheet and hold it / hang it right behind the scenery. An orange one for a fire effect, a blue one for a cold effect, etc. More info: https://www.google.com/search?q=using+bed+sheets+as+backdrops

Comment: Unless you get into lighting, the color of the screen matters. If you use a green screen, you have to keep all the reflected green light out of your shot. If you use a screen that's the color of the background and environment, you don't have to use special lighting for it and it will add good lighting to your model

Comment: Not an answer or an available solution at the moment, but it will be soon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTe_-YOccdM

Comment: @walen [Please put your answers in the answer section even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a chromakey – “green screen” or “blue screen” – backdrop, and use a chromakey app on your iPhone or iPad to change the background to whatever you like.

A dedicated chromakey screen can be had for as little as $15 US, or you could just use a couple sheets from a roll of colored kraft paper.

Comment: If you want to be cheap, you can use a single-coloured bedsheet or similar as well

Answer (score 8):

> What is the most cost effective way of recreating this effect at home - ideally using iPhone or iPad photo editing software.

Assuming you play in someone's home, and that someone is well equipped in the entertainment department, play in front of a very large TV, connected to a computer to display a chosen image.

This is very cost effective if you already have the computer and TV -- an HDMI cable to connect the two is around $20, and images are free(ish).

Comment: Very easy to end up with moire effect if you’re not careful.

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be done with pptx...where u can add a backdrop and superimpose your photo, removing elements you dont want.   Using a sheet with a solid color will make even easier.  Under format - you can select remove background - and the work is done for you...assuming you have PPTx

Comment: Sorry, what is PPTx?

Comment: Did you just propose Power Points as a means to editing photos? O_o

Comment: Not for editing photos per se.   You take your photo of your scenery....ideally with a sheet or other solid color backdrop.   Then, if you have powerpoint pptx,, u paste the image in.   Select remove background.   Its a very simple tool, if you have no other software.    You can then paste your inage over a background that matches your scene.     Time permitting ill find an example on youtube or creare one later.

Comment: Here is a youtube showing you how to remove backgrround in PPTx   https://youtu.be/OpjvNhsM0aQ